# use template for the selected value not just the option, ng-select2-component

Tags: angular

I am using ng-select2-component in an Angular project. I am able to use the templates input to display the options, but the selected option does not show with the template.
[image]

here is what I have

```
  <select2
        *ngIf="languages$ | async as languages"
        [data]="languages"
        [(ngModel)]="userData.languageId"
        [value]="userData.languageId"
        [templates]="selectTemplate"
        name="language"
      >
        <ng-template #selectTemplate let-label="label" let-data="data">
          <span class="m-1" [ngClass]="data.icon"></span>
          <span class="m-1">{{ label }}</span>
        </ng-template>
      </select2>
```

Comment: Where is option not displayed after selection ?

Comment: on the top, in the picture I posted you can see that the english does not have a flag like the option for it.

Comment: When you select English-UK , then this option is not shown to drop down , right ?

Comment: no, the proper selection is shown, but it is not shown with teh flag like it is in the option

Comment: Can you show me sample of whats value for `data.icon`  ? @chaimm

Comment: 'data.icon` is just a class, "flag-icon flag-icon-es"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232700/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-chaimm). @chaimm

Comment: sure, what is the solution?